# External data in Android

Tags: android

I have hardcoded data in my Android application. This will be in tree format. like this

```
<makes>
<make>
<name>abc</name>
<id>1</id>
</make>
... 10 more entries.
</makes>
```

Since this data will be hard coded, in my application, what can i use to easily parse in in my application. I can simply load it from my assets directory, and use xml parsing, but is there any inbuilt ways to use it. I know i can make a String array from xml resource, but how can i use this structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could easily store that table as an `SQLite` database. This [link](http://coenraets.org/blog/androidtutorial/) might be helpful, particularly step 6.

Comment: Thats seems a very nice way to hard code, data in the application. Are there any cons of using this technique ?

Comment: One con of the listview in step 6 is that it's acessing db in that main thread. It could result in ANR.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the XmlResourceParser class, that implements the XmlPullParser interface, and will allow you to [parse the XML file](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html), loading it from the resources folder. After that, I would recommend defining a Make class with the two properties defined in the XML and populate a List or other type of data structure with objects of that class while you loop through the xml file.